# PHP JOIN LEFT WHERE wont work. what have i done wrong?

Tags: php, join

```
 $sql= "SELECT name, content FROM {$dbpraefix}meta_global 
           UNION SELECT name, content FROM {$dbpraefix}meta_local 
           LEFT JOIN {$dbpraefix}pages ON {$dbpraefix}pages.id={$dbpraefix}meta_local.page 
           WHERE {$dbpraefix}pages.alias = $_GET['include']";
```

Hello Everyone. whats wrong with the last part of my code.

```
WHERE {$dbpraefix}pages.alias = $_GET['include']"
```

my page doesnt work. but if i throw the last part, it works well. 
this is a part of my "build your own CMS" projekt.
thanks for your answers.

Comment: check for errors via PHP and whatever RDBMS you're using.

Comment: what's the value of your GET array btw?

Comment: More importantly, this code is incredibly open for injection. I could put anything for the `include` variable and inject directly into the query. Very scary stuff. I'd suggest researching PDO or Mysqli

Comment: I have a name filter. (Its stings array) does it still dangerous? Should i avoid get_include at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : add single quote

```
$sql= "SELECT name, content FROM {$dbpraefix}meta_global 
           UNION SELECT name, content FROM {$dbpraefix}meta_local 
           LEFT JOIN {$dbpraefix}pages ON {$dbpraefix}pages.id={$dbpraefix}meta_local.page 
           WHERE {$dbpraefix}pages.alias = '".$_GET['include']."'";
```

Comment: sure, if it's a string. But we don't know that yet ;-)

Comment: Yes its string thanks  alot.  But what if its a number (int, double etc) sorry newbie question :)

Comment: @SyarifMathis In that case you can skip the quotes, no problem occurs if you use quotes